# Can i validate multiple multiple form element where element name starts by abc

Tags: javascript

I have a form where two text boxes are presented. They both have respective name values: name = "pname" & name = "pname2".

So, can i validate them by calling their name as "^pname".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, can i validate them by calling their name as "^pname".

yes, try

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[name^='pname']");
for( var counter = 0; counter < inputs.length; counter++)
{
   validate(inputs.item(counter).value); //do your validation on the inputs one by one
}
```

As per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

> **[attr^=value]**
>
> Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and
> whose value is prefixed by "value".